# Pushing a view controller with animation freezes UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to push a view controller for the same type more than once, and if I use animation in the push, the UI freezes after the pushController.

Example: I am in a ProductController and I do a pushViewController to another ProductController, after that the UI freeze.

The Xcode shows the following error: 
`*"[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7fdd9a5bdba0, UIView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES."*`

To avoid the UI freeze i have to do a pushController setting animated: false.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(productController, animated: false)
```

Any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Show the code that is actually causing your issue. Be sure to include enough details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wondering why this code doesn't work?

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(productController, animated: true)
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

If you use `animated = true`, the function queues up the action of pushing the view controller on the next pass through the app event loop. It doesn't happen right away.

Then, in the very next line, you ask to pop the view controller even though it hasn't started pushing it yet.

### tl;dr:

Don't do that.

However, the more important question is **why** would you push and then immediately pop a view controller? It seems pointless.

Comment: I edited the question to explain the problem properly. 
In a ProductController i have to do a pushController to another ProductController using animated = false, otherwise the UI freezes.

The same freeze ocurrs if do a popController of a ProductController to another ProductController using animated = true.